# Solution of system of linear equations.

Tags: matrix-equations

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ matrix and there is at least one non trivial solution for the system $Ax=0$.

For any real column vector $b$ with n components,the equation $Ax=b$ has:

$1.$Unique solution.

$2.$Finite many solutions.

$3.$Infinitely many solutions.

$4.$No solution.

I think first and second options are false.

I have problem about the third and fourth options and I think both could be true but I am not sure.

What you will suggest the answer?

Thanks

Comment: Take $b=0$, you know $Ax=0$ has at least one non-trivial solution (thus it has infinitely many...), hence (4) is excluded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct: $Ax = b$ will either have infinitely many solutions or no solutions. For example, take $n = 2$ and consider:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Notice that not all columns of $A$ contain a pivot, so $Ax = 0$ has (infinitely) many (nontrivial) solutions. Yet if:
$$
b = \begin{bmatrix}
7 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $Ax = b$ has no solution. On the other hand, if:
$$
b = \begin{bmatrix}
7 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.